# Find all values of $c$ such that $\{(1,c,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,-c)\}$ are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Find all values of $c$ such that $\{(1,c,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,-c)\}$ are linearly independent.

So, my strategy is to consider these vectors  as column vectors, and then form a matrix with them as the columns. Once I do that, I will employ Gauss-Jordan elimination to find an equivalent matrix except in reduced row echelon form.

I typed the matrix into matlab and asked it to find the reduced row echelon form, and it gave me the identity matrix. Thus, I believe that no matter what value I pick for $c$, these vectors will be linearly independent.

However, upon trying to employ the Gauss-Jordan elimination by hand, I have a $1-c^2$ in the $(3,3)$ position. Then I got to thinking, if $c \in \{ \pm 1\}$ then this would be zero, and I could not use it to eliminate the entry above it, and thus I would not be able to reduce this to the identity matrix.

Then I thought some more, and wondered if I would have employed different row operations get to reduced row echelon form, then maybe a different situation like this would have arisen... So now I am very confused and don't know how to do the problem!!

Help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's a little long. Instead, directly compute the determinant of the matrix and eliminate the cases where this determinant is $0$ (for this, you have to solve a quadratic equation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to compute the determinant of the matrix$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\c&0&1\\0&1&-c\end{bmatrix},$$which is $c^2-1$ Therefore, the vectors are linearly independent if and only if $c\ne\pm1$. Or you can row reduce the matrix $A$. If you add to the second line the first one times $-c$, you get$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&-c&1\\0&1&-c\end{bmatrix}.$$Now, if you exchange the last two rows, you get$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&-c\\0&-c&1\end{bmatrix}.$$If now you subtract the second row from the first one and if you add to the third row the second one times $c$, you get$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&c\\0&1&-c\\0&0&1-c^2\end{bmatrix}.$$This matrix is invertible if and only if $c^2\ne1$, and so those three vectors are linearly independent if and only if $c^2\ne1$.

Comment: Hmm.. Unforuntately we have not yet learned about determinants yet. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, should you wish to take a more..conservative approach for the vectors to be independent, they must satisfy the condition:

$$l_1(1,c,0)+l_2(1,0,1)+l_3(0,1,-c)=(0,0,0)\Rightarrow l_1=l_2=l_3=0$$

We notice that $$l_1(1,c,0)+l_2(1,0,1)+l_3(0,1,-c)\Rightarrow \\(l_1+l_2,cl_1+l_3,l_2-cl_3)=(0,0,0)\Rightarrow \\l_1=-l_2\\cl_1+l_3=0\\l_2-cl_3=0$$

or equivalently $$-cl_2+l_3=0\\l_2-cl_3=0$$

by multiplying the second relationship with $c$ and then adding them, we obtain $l_3-c^2l_3=0$ or $l_3(c^2-1)=0$. But we want $l_3=0$ to hold for any $c$, thus we must have $c^2\neq1$